# How to get a two-dimensional array from a Postgre using java or jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql, arrays, spring, postgresql

When I execute such code in the console

```
SELECT dimensions FROM public."NEWS" WHERE id = 5
```

I get this : (arrays of integers)

```
{{2560,1707},{2560,1707},{720,960},{1200,1600}}
```

But when I wrote code in java

```
ArrayList<String[][]> dimensions = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    PreparedStatement ps =
        dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT dimensions::varchar[][] FROM public.\"NEWS\" WHERE id = "+id+";");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        dimensions.add((String[][]) rs.getArray(1).getArray());
    }
} catch (SQLException ignored) {}
```

I got NullPointerException on line: `dimensions.add((String[][]) rs.getArray(1).getArray());`

How to get a two-dimensional array from a Postgre using java or jdbcTemlate from Spring Framework?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need that response as a two dimensional array. Unless you absolutely need a 2D array, you should not mapping your rows as arrays.

Comment: This is an Oracle question?

Comment: @Karl Nicholas. I do not understand what the name of the company has in common with my question. If you mean Oracle Database -  I don't use Oracle Database. Postgresql database and java 8 with Spring Framework. And Spring's class JdbcTemplate.

Comment: @Chad Yes, I can convert a column into a one-dimensional array. Just somehow sad that I did not can use 2D arrays

Comment: Looks like org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray is meant to be used for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the code at [8.15. Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), this bit of code seems to work just fine:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb",
        "testdb",
        "testdb");

ResultSet rs = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sal_emp").executeQuery();

rs.next();

java.sql.Array a1 = rs.getArray(2);
Integer[] o1 = (Integer[])a1.getArray();

java.sql.Array a2 = rs.getArray(3);
String[][] o2 = (String[][])a2.getArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me!!!  (I changed Integer[] to Integer[][] and index 2 and 3 to 1) =)

Comment: Yea, I was thinking you were getting Integer arrays ... welcome.